# Publish URI over HTTP

Tags: uri, rdf, semantic-web, linked-data

My graduation project is titled as "Web Storytelling using dynamic Semantic Publishing". It's all about taking a query from the user and show the result in the form of a story that contains text and images, these data will be extracted from google search resulted links for that query.
But I'm confused about something, I want to use linked data techniques , what I did first that i collected the data and put them in RDF format but right now i'm confused about what is called URI.
as my rdf has a lot of triples that describe some entities and some sentences , Is that necessary to make for every subject in my rdf that describe sentences a URI that dereferencable over HTTP ?
or can i make uri for each story or article that I'll make at run time and when the user Query them again I'll have an rdf and html representation for that article. 
so to sum up Is that a must to make for every triple a URI that dereferencable over HTTP even if that triple describe sentences? And If i have An rdf describe entities can i use the URI in owl:sameas to get the representation from other site like dbpedia by 303 response instead of making for every resource representation in rdf or html ?

Comment: Could you please clarify the meaning of the last question (starting with "And If i have An rdf describe entities can i [...]) - preferably by editing the question? Also, using text formatting you can separate the questions so that they are not in one big chunk of text.

Comment: Hi, achieved any progress here?